# Layout options in UITableView (iPhone)? Or extend UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, layout, uiscrollview

I'm new to Objective-C and iPhone coding and was hoping someone could help me.

Basically I want a scrollable table that displays a name and a quantity of that item.  For example:
Apples.........2
Oranges......4
Bananas......5

I want the name to be left-justified and the number to be right-justified.

Is there any way to do this with a UITableView or will I need to extend UIScrollView?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `cell.text` to "Apples".  Then create an new UILabel view with the text "2" and assigned it to `cell.accessoryView`.

Text is always on the left, and accessory views are always on the right.  Optionally a UIImage in `cell.image` will be displayed to the left of the cell text if you choose to add one.

If you have a cell layout more complicated than that you have to add subviews to your cell manually.

Comment: I think "a cell layout core complicated" was supposed to be "a cell layout MORE complicated" :)

Answer (score 1):

One not too difficult option is to subclass UITableViewCell with one label for the text and one label for the number, then just set the label values.

If you want the ... that you've shown then you could probably use a standard UITableViewCell and write some code to feed the cell text that has been pre-modified to fit in the space alloted.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use another CellType, which is already provided by apple and change the color for the detailTextLabel:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Apples";
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"2";
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    return cell;
}
```

No need to bother with subclassing or adding labels on your own.